# PyCharm & IronPython Codecompletion?

Tags: python, .net, intellisense, pycharm

I have PyCharm 3.0 installed for Windows and installed IronPython 2.7.4 installed.
But it appears that i am not able to get references and it wont recognize .net classes to some degree.

Let me give you a simple example:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")

from System.Windows.Forms import MessageBox
MessageBox.Show("Hello World")
```

i can run/execute it perfectly fine but the IDE shows me that it cannot recognize System
[image: http://i.imgur.com/Aml9DuM.png]

As you can imagine this is somewhat... frustrating to put it mildly, pressing alt+enter and then Generate stubs for Binray Module XXXXX" and then pressing Fix all unresolved reference problems will not resolve it as i would like to be able to lookup class definitions for .net classes.

So if anyone has managed to get this to work I would appreciate the Insight. Yes i know that i can use IronPython in Python Tools for Visual Studio but i would like to be able to work in PyCharm aswell.

Just for reference this is what i get in Python Tools for visual studio and what i want to happen in PyCharm
[image]

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be a bug in PyCharm, I've [reported it here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11636), please vote.

Comment: Thanks, i hope this will get fixed soon =/